# How to fix loading issue with flutter app on apk release

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-getx, state-management

I am building a flutter app. I use Getx State Management. I fetch the data from internet using Getxservices

The app works fine on debug but I face this issue on apk-release. First when I install the app on android phone, it will work perfectly like this:

[image]

**But when I close the app and re-open it, I will have a screen like this:**

[image]

Below is my AndroidManifest

[image]

The app works fine on debug mode so there is no way I can debug it to know the exact thing causing the issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you share the code through github if possible? It could help us to go through and fix the issue

Comment: @JabeedAhmed file more than 25MB

Comment: @VirginusAlajekwu-DonSolace You can push it to github

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have gotten the solution. I added splash screen and loaded all my resources on splash screen and the issue is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Give internet permission in your AndroidManifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="...">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> 
</manifest>
```

Comment: I did that already

Comment: I included the manifest file in the question now